# Python Detecting duplicated strings in a dataframe column

Tags: string, loops, split, duplicates

I have under the University column, the multiple strings of university extracted from the person's resume. But the results contains many dupes. This is what the value under university is like ['university of washington bachelor of science', 'university of washington', 'information school undergraduate researcher']. I wanted to comma separate the string to get each of the individual string and only to include the string if it's not contained by another one. So in this case only university of washington bachelor of science and information school undergraduate reseacher. Here is the code I tried on this row. And it doesn't yield the correct result. So I tried to comma separate the long string first and loop over the split elements. And inside the loop I'll check if my list is empty, if yes then append the first element, if no then check if the existing string in the list contains the new element, if yes do nothing, if no check whether the element contains the existing then whether replace or add the new element.

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
lst=[]
element=row.UNIVERSITY.split(',')
for candidate in element:
    if not lst:
        lst.append(candidate)
        print('This is the first item'+ candidate)
        print('current lst:'+ str(lst))
    else:
        for existing in lst:
            print('This is what we have in the list now'+ existing)
            if existing in candidate:
                lst.remove(existing)
                lst.append(candidate)
                print('dupe detected')
            elif candidate in existing:
                continue
            else:
                st.append(candidate)
                print('new item'+ candidate)
    
    
    
print(lst)
```

And for the outputs I get:

```
This is the first item['university of washington bachelor of science'
current lst:["['university of washington bachelor of science'"]
This is what we have in the list now['university of washington bachelor of science'
new item 'university of washington'
This is what we have in the list now['university of washington bachelor of science'
new item 'information school undergraduate researcher']
["['university of washington bachelor of science'"]
```

I do not know why university of washington got passed into the else loop and therefore seeing 'new item university of washington' and I do not know why information school undergraduate researcher is not in the final list either. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I see one issue, if your list is ["hello","there"] and you add "hello there" it will remove hello and add "hello there" but ignore "there"

This is because your for loop takes actions while looping, before checking every element. To fix it, I recommend looping twice

```
boolean good=true
//check if candidate is a substring of an element
for element in lst:
   if candidate in existing:
      //candidate is bad, move to next candidate, however you want to do that
      good=false
if(good):
   //now we know we will add candidate, so we remove all elements that are a substring of candidate:
   for element in lst:
      if element in candidate:
         st.remove(element)
   //now we can add candidate (we do this last so we don't remove it when <element=candidate> in candidate = true)
   st.add(candidate)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this out!